# Android version of AVAudioPlayer's averagePowerForChannel

Tags: android, iphone, audio

Does Android have a similar method to the iPhone `AVAudioPlayer's` averagePowerForChannel?

I want to get an average reading of the amplitude of as a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in function but you can calculate it yourself.

To do this, calculate the root-mean-square average of continuous samples.

```
rms = sqrt((sample0^2 + sample1^2 + sample2^2 + sample3^2) / numberOfSamples)
```

The following links should be helpful to you as they contain the full source code to two excellent Android sound related projects.

[Ringdroid](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/)

[Rehearsal Assistant](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/rehearsalassist/wiki)